# question about proof of the closed range of Fredholm operators

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand the following proof:

[image]

So everything makes sense but for the operator that I have highlighted, I am actually not sure why that is a bounded operator. I tried finding a bound and got stuck. Do we have to use the fact that the complement $Z$ is finite dimensional?

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall y\in\pi(x)\quad\|Tx\|=\|Ty\|\le\|T\|\|y\|$$
hence
$$\|Tx\|\le\|T\|\|\pi(x)\|.$$